# C# code extract FROM methods

Tags: c#, methods, refactoring, code-duplication, automated-refactoring

Does someone know a c# tool that could extract all code in given class from methods?

Example starting file:

```
public class HelloWorld
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Print("Hello, ");
        Print("World");
        PrintExclamationMark();
    }

    private static void Print(string text)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine(text);
    }

    private static void PrintExclamationMark();
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("!");
    }
}
```

Result I would like to get after using the tool on given class/file:

```
public class HelloWorld
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("Hello, ");
        System.Console.WriteLine("World");
        System.Console.WriteLine("!");
    }
}
```

Such tool could be very helpful when I extracting a lot of new methods and double checking if no code was omitted.

Comment: Please put more effort into formatting your code when you post it - the indentation is all messed up... it's easy enough to fix, but it's better to do it before you post. Look at the preview, and ask yourself whether that's the best formatting you could achieve.

Comment: On a separate note, I'd encourage you to rewrite `if (null != item)` to `if (item != null)` as the latter is generally more conventional - the "constant first" approach to conditions was really to avoid accidental assignment in languages which don't have as strong typing for conditions; it's not relevant in C# generally, and even in those languages where it *was* relevant, typically compilers will generate a warning now.

Comment: Finally, it's really not clear to me what you're asking. Why would you "paste same code repeatedly into the file"? It sounds like what you're really looking for is using refactoring tools to make the Extract Method refactoring reliable...

Comment: Old file and new one should be different only in looks. That means that by deleting all methods and pasting same code into one place from any of these 2 files I should end up with same result. 
Doing this by hand would take too much time and it includes human mistake. I would like generate such methodless files automatically.

Comment: Nope, it's still really unclear to me what you're asking, I'm afraid. Maybe someone else will find it clearer...

Comment: I have changed code example and included the result I would like to get after using automatic method removal

Comment: What would you expect it to do if you were calling `Print` in a loop that depended on user input, or something similar? Basically, I think the answer is "No, this is infeasible for most situations - use refactoring tools instead."

Comment: You would end up with `System.Console.WriteLine(iterableValueToPrint)` instead of `Print(iterableValueToPrint)`

Comment: I don't see how that helps, I'm afraid. I really think you should give up on this approach and just use the tools that *do* exist... and comprehensive testing, of course.

Comment: If you are using Visual Studio as your IDE you could search the VS market place website to see if there are any extensions to VS that analyse your classes and perform the refactoring that you seek. Having said that, such a VS extension would be quite complex so if it does exist would likely be a paid-for extension rather than a free one. Alternatively you could create your own VS extension, which could be bespoke to your classes if you wanted - not necessarily an easy VS extension to write, especially if it was your first, but if you want to pursue simply bingle "vsix" to get started.